# Apache - disabling automatic rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm just beginning to test my usage of mod_rewrite on a local apache setup.

While rewrite rules are working fine, my problem is that a page like "localhost/foo/" is automatically redirected to "localhost/foo.php". This happens even with no rewrite rules. Is this normal? I assume not, since this does not happen on my hosted domain. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was - documenting it as an answer for future searchers [is this the correct procedure?]

I had to disable [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html) - it was redirecting localhost/foo to localhost/foo.php if it could find that file. Everything worked just fine once that was done.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of rewrite is going on.  You could rename the actual module on disk to make sure its not used.  In Linux it is /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: Simply disabling the module won't work for me, since I want to create my own rewrite rules. Where could this rewrite be going on, so that I can remove it?

Comment: Its going to be somewhere.  On a Linux box: `cd /etc/httpd; grep RewriteRule */*`

Comment: Hey maybe its the `DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.shtml index.cgi index.php`

Comment: That should only refer to the index.php file though, right? Not any other php files..

Comment: Yes, DirectoryIndex sets what file is displayed when the URL is a folder like http://localhost/foo/

Comment: The line just says - DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm. This seems to be normal, right?